# Center two variable width columns

Tags: html, css

I have two columns separated by a fixed margin which have a variable width. I'd like to center these:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto">
    <div style="background: red; float:left; margin-right: 10px">
        sdf
    </div>
    <div style="background: red; float:left">
        sdfsd
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hSGTq/

If I fix the width of wrapper `div` it will work, but I am not sure how to get it to work with a variable width. I'd prefer not to use Javascript if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about display:table?

Comment: you need to define the size of each column, at least in percentage. 50% width for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` on the internal divs and `text-align:center` on the wrapping div

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X6VWZ/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap" style="margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="inner" style="background: red; margin-right: 10px">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: red; ">
        <p>Lorem sit amet, .</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding:1em;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Whilst other solutions may work - this is the one I decided to go with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;width:100px">
  <div style="background: red;float:left;margin-right: 10px">
    sdf
  </div>
  <div style="background: red;float:left">
    sdfsd
  </div>
</div>
```

just add width (eg. 100PX)  and you will get your div center

Answer (score 0):

Try to user `display:table`

Markup:

```
<div class="outer" style="margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="inner" style="background: red;">
        sdf
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: red;">
        sdfsd
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.outer{
    display:table;
    border-spacing:10px;
}
.inner{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/j9uJh/2/)